# edit typface on customListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, fonts, custom-adapter, typeface

I have to change the typeface on a custom list adapter.
I've a problem, because i can't get the current context.

```
getassets() not exist for the class
getApplicationcontext()  not exist for the class
getBaseContext()  not exist for the class
```

i'm trying to get the context from the view, there're no error, but font not change

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        Context  context = convertView.getContext();
//or
       Context  context2 = parent.getContext();
```

after in the code i write

```
 bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Jennifer-Lynne.ttf");
        italic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica-italic.ttf");
        holder.titoloView.setTypeface(bold);
        holder.autoreView.setTypeface(italic);
```

idea?

Comment: i'm sorry (and i'm an idiot)
I'm working on a backup copy.. i lose 3 hour of my life -.-

i'm put the working code on answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct code (font on assets folder)

Global variable

```
Typeface tf, bold, italic;
   Context prova;
```

the metod where i set the context

```
public CopyOfCustomListAdapterLele(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        prova = context;
    }
```

and the setting of the font

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;


        bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(prova.getAssets(), "fonts/Jennifer-Lynne.ttf");



        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singolopunto, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titoloView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); //titolo canzone

            holder.imageView = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); //immagine
            holder.free = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3); //immagine free

            holder.titoloView.setTypeface(bold);


...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Context to your CustomListAdapter class constructor and use that to get your font from the assets. Set the font when you initialize your ViewHolder views (when convertView is null in getView).